# Creating Popup programmatically in WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

How to create the popup in program? e.g. I need to rename the file in phone App. How to do this by using popup in wp7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the **Input Prompt** control in the [Coding4Fun Windows Phone Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Can we Cancel the InputPrompt.. If so how?

Comment: Cancelling is performed by pushing the "Back" button, which is the expected action to perform a "cancel" in WP7.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `Popup` element to your XAML and define the content using regular elements (as you would any other `Page` or `UserControl`. Set the `Popup.IsOpen` property to `true` to show the `Popup` and `false` to close the `Popup`. The following XAML shows an example that I use for showing in-application "toast" notifications with the [Silverlight Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com)

```
<Popup x:Name="_toast">
    <Grid x:Name="_toastContainer"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}">
        <StackPanel Margin="14,10">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Comment: I want this popup tobe in Data template..?

Comment: That complicates things. I'd actually recommend using a single `Popup` that you can access as I illustrated above and if necessary update the content of the `Popup`. If you absolutely **must** have the `Popup` in the `DataTemplate`, then you'll need to traverse the visual tree to find the relevant `Popup` element to toggle it's `IsOpen` property.